# Is there a way I can batch rename files in a folder with user input?

Tags: python, python-3.x, rename, file-rename

Wish to have user input rename batch photo files but with the end suffix changing.

Every couple of months I get given the same job, rename hundreds of photos. It takes me hours if not days to do. I so far have the code asking for the type of test (that the photo is capturing), the number of the test, the depth the test was conducted from and to from user input.

but I have hit a snag, I want to be able to batch rename but different photos show different depths. So for example I want the photos to be names: 
BH01_0-5m
then the next photo be named. 
BH01_5-10m

But I only know how to code it so everything gets named BH01_0-5m

This is the code that I have so far for user input:

```
borehole = raw_input("What type of geotechnical investigation?")
type(borehole)

number = raw_input("What number is this test?")
type(number)

frommetre = raw_input("From what depth (in metres)?")
type(frommetre)

tometre = raw_input("What is the bottom depth(in metres)?")
type(tometre)

name = (borehole+number+"_"+frommetre+"-"+tometre)
print(name)
```

I get the title I would want for the first photo file but if I have like 4 photos in each folder they at the moment would get renamed the same exact thing as the user input. I am hoping to make the suffix sequential in lots of 5 metres (0-5, 5-10, 10-15, 15-20, 20-25 etc...).

Comment: Your code shows how the name of the first photo is built up. But what is the name of the original files? How many sets of photos will be in the input folder? Perhaps if you provide a bit more information about the inputs, you can get some tips on how to approach the problem.

Comment: There will be between 3-6 photos in each folder with 52ish folders for each project. The original name for the photos is the random date names that the phones and cameras set for them

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm making a few assumptions here:

- the name of the folder is the name of the borehole
- the filenames for each borehole may differ, but when sorted alpha-numerically, the first one will be the one closest to the surface
- all sets need increments of 5 metres

What you're looking to do, can be done in two nested loops:

- for all folders:
- for all files in each folder:
- rename the file to match the folder name and some depth sequentially

Here's an example:

```
from pathlib import Path
from shutil import move

root_folder = 'c:\\temp'
for folder in Path(root_folder).iterdir():
    if folder.is_dir():
        startDepth = 0
        step = 5
        for file in Path(folder).iterdir():
            if file.is_file():
                new_name = f'{folder.name}_{str(startDepth).zfill(3)}-{str(startDepth + step).zfill(3)}{file.suffix}'
                print(f'would rename {str(file)} to {str(file.parent / Path(new_name))}')
                # move(str(file), str(file.parent / Path(new_name)))
                startDepth += step
```

Note that I've also added `.zfill(3)` to each depth, since I think you'll prefer names like `BH01_000-005.jpg` to `BH01_0-5.jpg`, since they will sort more nicely.

Note that this script only prints what it would do, you can simply comment out the `print` statement and remove the comment symbol in front of the `move` statement and it will actually rename files.

Comment: +1 for solid answer. If you want to, you could consider automatically renaming the files using `os` or `subprocess` to call a shell and, for example, running `os.system('ren '+file+' '+new_name)`

Comment: @101arrowz I would prefer the solution given, using shutil.move, since this will use whatever is appropriate for the operating system it is running on, instead of relying on a command called `ren` on the current system - but if it's available, it's likely similar in effect for a file set this small.

Comment: I didn't even see that part commented out, oops. Very nice! I assumed Windows because corporate environment.

Comment: Thankyou very much. Yes your assumptions are 100% correct.

Comment: @E.Jayne feel free to accept the answer to close the question (or ask for additional details, if you feel the answer isn't complete)